# Regular language where syntactic right congruence and syntactic congruence differ

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

> Find an example of a regular language where the syntactic right congruence and the syntactic congruence are not identical.

I have gone through the relevant definitions and understand them, but could not figure out an example for this case.

Comment: Take the language $L=\{ab,abb\}$ over $\Sigma=\{a,b\}$. If $\sim_L$ and $\sim_R$ denote the left and right congruences, then $ab\sim_L abb$, since $zab$ and $zabb$ are not in $L$ for all non-empty $z\in\Sigma^*$ and $zab,zabb\in L$ for $z=\epsilon$. On the other hand, $ab\not\sim_R abb$, since $abz\in L$ and $abbz\not\in L$, for $z=b$.

Comment: I think by syntactic congruence refers to the equivalence classes obtained if we consider any language. I am not sure how to interpret this answer in the context of the equivalence classes. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Let L be the language over A = {a,b} of words of even length. The syntactic congruence has two classes, L itself and L1, the words of odd length. [Got this from wikipedia]

Comment: See the definitions in the [answer below](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/136721/125618).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Definition:** An equivalence relation $\sim$ on $\Sigma^*$ is a *right (left) congruence* if $x\sim y$ implies $xv\sim yv$ (respectively $vx\sim vy$) for every $x, y, v \in\Sigma^*$.

**Definition:** Given a language $L$ over an alphabet $\Sigma$, the *canonical right congruence* $\sim_L$ is defined by $x\sim_L y$ if and only if for all $z\in\Sigma^*$ we have $xz\in L\iff yz\in L$. Similarly, for the *canonical left congruence* $x{}_{L}\sim y$ if for all $z\in\Sigma^*$ we have that $zx\in L\iff zy\in L$.

**Example:** Consider the (regular) language $L=\{ab,abb\}$ over $\Sigma^*$. For this language, the relations $\sim_L$ and ${}_L\sim$ are not the same.

In fact, according to ${}_L\sim$ the words $x=ab$ and $y=abb$ are in the same class. This is because if we prepend any $z\in\Sigma^*$ to $x$ and $y$, both word $zx$ and $zy$ are in $L$ or not simultaneously. In fact, for $z=\epsilon$ both $zx=\epsilon ab=ab$ and $zy=\epsilon abb=abb$ are in $L$. However, when $z\neq \epsilon$, then both $zx$ and $zy$ are not in $L$. Therefore $ab{}_L\sim abb$.

Now, when we consider the relation $\sim_L$, we have that $ab\not\sim_L abb$. In fact, if we take $z=b$ we get that $xz=abb\in L$ but $yz=abbb\not\in L$.

So, the regular language $L$ is an example for which its left and right canonical congruences are not the same relation.